# Where do I have to specify the run-list in local-mode?

Tags: chef-infra

How can in configure the chef-client to know the run_list to run every 15min?

I start the chef-client run with "chef-client --local-mode -j run_list.json" which works as expected.

To provide a chef run every 15min, I add the chef client cookbook as dependency. In the log file I can see that the chef run starts (in local mode) every 15min, but the run_list is empty for every further run.

Where do I have to add the information that the second chef-run should use the same run-list as in the first run? I couldn`t find any place in the client.rb file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can define you own attributes within a json file and use it as a part of the `chef-client` run.

for instance, having an json file named `attrs.json` that look like:

```
{
  "run_list": [
    "'recipe[base::default]'"
  ]
}
```

use `chef-client` in conjunction with [`--json-attributes`, something like:

```sh
chef-client --local-mode --json-attributes /path/to/attrs.json
```

or you can use `chef-client` in conjunction with `--runlist`

```sh
chef-client --local-mode --runlist 'recipe[base::default]'
```

if the `node_path` setting is used in `chef-client` confiugration, [`client.rb`](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client/#settings), after `chef-client` run, a `node.json` file will be written to the `node_path`, which can be used as a presistency for a periodically execution.