# Using knife commands anywhere in terminal and without "bundle exec"

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I recently moved to Catalina on a formatted drive. In the past I was able to run `knife` from any directory on my terminal.

At the moment, it only runs from the chef repo it was installed in and it only runs when I prefix it with `bundle exec`

Can't find any documentation on the matter and I'm not super-savvy with terminal/bash/zsh nuances - any tips would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will advise you to keep using [bundler](https://bundler.io/) if you care of running multiple version of chef-client, so you can update chef-client from time to time and keep things work smoothly.

you can specify the chef-client version in the `Gemfile` in your project such as

```
group :default do
  gem 'chef', '15.8.23'
end
```

you can make chef-client more streamed lined by providing [chef-client a json attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61423345/1184717) file (specifying cookbooks attribute, etc) and a [client configuration](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client/) (specifying chef-client settings, such as a cookbook directory, etc.) and store them in the project repository.

otherwise, you can [install](https://downloads.chef.io/chef-workstation#mac_os_x) [chef workstation which](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/) bundles chef-client (chef infra client) or only [chef infra client](https://downloads.chef.io/chef#mac_os_x) (make sure the desired version  you need).

see the [macos installtion](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/install_workstation/#macos) or use [brew](https://brew.sh/) to tap to [homebrew-chef](https://github.com/chef/homebrew-chef)

```sh
brew cask install chef/chef/chef-workstation
```

or only chef infra client

```sh
brew cask install chef/chef/chef-infra-client
```